# How, in XAML, can I reference a non-static property without using a data-binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working with a converter -

```
public class EnumSwitchConverter :  ConverterBase {
    private object
        _On = null,
        _Off = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set object returned when parameter is present in value.
    /// </summary>
    public object On {
        get { return this._On; }
        set { this._On = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set object returned when parameter is not present in value.
    /// </summary>
    public object Off {
        get { return this._Off; }
        set { this._Off = value; }
    }

    public override object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
        return ( ( Enum )value ).HasFlag( ( Enum )parameter )
            ? this.On : this.Off;
    }
}
```

( `ConverterBase` is just an abstract class which implements `MarkupExtension`, `IValueConverter` and `IMultiValueConverter` because I got tired of doing that manually ).

I want to use this converter to bind to an Enum property. As indicated above, when the enum is the specified value, the converter returns whatever is set to the `On` property, and when it is not, the converter returns whatever is set to the `Off` property. I want to pass two different commands to the `On` and `Off` properties. In doing, when the bound enum matches the target value, the button will call the command set to the `On` property, and when it does not, the button will call the command set to the `Off` property.

```
<Button Command="{Binding
    PropertySource.SomeEnumProperty,
    Source={x:Static Application.Current},
    Converter={myConverters:EnumConverter
        On={}, Off={}}
    ConverterParameter={x:Static myEnum:enumValue}/>
```

I have two properties that expose the commands that I want to go into On and Off.

```
public partial class App : Application { 
    /*Stuff*/
    public ICommand onCommand{ get{ return this._onCommand; } }
    public ICommand offCommand{ get{ return this._offCommand; } }
}
```

I don't want to do the following -

```
On={Binding OnCommand, Source={x:Static Application.Current}
```

First, `OnCommand` will never change. Second, `On` is not a dependency property, so I couldn't do it anyway. I just want to pass `OnCommand` as a reference to the `On` property of the converter.

How would I reference the command properties in my converter?

Comment: Give `App` a static `Current` property that returns `(App)Application.Current` and use `{x:Static App.Current.onCommand}` etc.

Comment: @EdPlunkett `{x:static App.Instance.OnCommand}` - "Nested types are not supported: App.Instance."

Comment: OK, just tested it. It had to be `{x:Static local:App.Current.onCommand}` anyway, but then it didn't work because (I think) the whole property path has to be static. However, I tried making `OnCommand` a static property of `App` and this worked: `{x:Static local:App.OnCommand}`.

Comment: You could also write another `MarkupExtension`, which takes an enum saying which command you want (or a string for a property name), and gets that from `(App)Application.Current` with an if/else, or a switch, or reflection. (On second thought, that could only realistically give you the value of the property at the time the MarkupExtension is evaluated, which may or may not be useful).

Comment: @EdPlunkett So the only way to reference a property is if I use a binding, or if the property is static? That can't be the case. There has to be some way to reference non-static properties without using a binding...

Comment: Why don't you make your EnumSwitchConverter class inherit from DependenyObject and make On and Off dependency properties?

Comment: @mm8 Because creating bindings within a converter feels very counter-intuitive to me. In addition, the properties will never change, so why would I ever need, or even want, to create a binding just to reference something that won't ever change, ever? I mean, yes it WOULD work, but it just feels wrong.

Comment: @mm8 Then it can't inherit from `MarkupExtension`, for one thing.

Comment: You could set a dependency property using the StaticResource markup extension. It doesn't have to be a binding.

Comment: @mm8 On the other hand, yeah, that just means you have to make it a resource instead of tossing it inline there. Or write yet another MarkupExtension that returns the DependencyObject/IValueConverter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this, offhand (plus a third way that @mm8 pointed out):

1. Make the commands static.

   ```
   public partial class App : Application { 
       public static ICommand OnCommand { get{ return _onCommand; } }
       public static ICommand OffCommand { get{ return _offCommand; } }
   }
   ```

   XAML

   ```
   <Button 
       Command="{Binding
           PropertySource.SomeEnumProperty,
           Source={x:Static Application.Current},
           Converter={myConverters:EnumConverter
               On={x:Static local:App.OnCommand}, 
               Off={x:Static local:App.OffCommand}}
           ConverterParameter={x:Static myEnum:enumValue}}"
       />
   ```
2. Leave the commands as instance properties and write another `MarkupExtension`.

   ```
   public class GetInstanceProp : MarkupExtension
   {
       public GetInstanceProp(String propname, Object source)
       {
           _source = source;
           _propName = propname;
       }

       private Object _source;
       private String _propName;

       public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
           var propInfo = _source.GetType().GetProperty(_propName);

           return propInfo.GetValue(_source);
       }
   }
   ```

   XAML

   ```
   <Button 
       Command="{Binding
           PropertySource.SomeEnumProperty,
           Source={x:Static Application.Current},
           Converter={myConverters:EnumConverter
               On={local:GetInstanceProp OnCommand, {x:Static local:App.Current}}, 
               Off={local:GetInstanceProp OffCommand, {x:Static local:App.Current}}
           ConverterParameter={x:Static myEnum:enumValue}}"
       />
   ```

   You need to understand what you're doing here: Markup extensions are evaluated once and only once, around when the XAML is parsed. It's a *markup* extension. `GetProp` will give you the value the property had *then*. That's OK if it's a command property with no setter, that's initialized in the constructor or the first time anybody calls the getter. That's the case we've got here. But very often, that's not the case.
3. Another option as mm8 suggests is to derive your valueconverter from `DependencyObject` rather than from MarkupExtension. That means you have to create an instance of it in resources, but that's not the end of the world. And then you can give it bindable dependency properties.

   If you're really fed up with the `StaticResource` value converter thing, you could write a `MarkupExtension` that returns an instance of the dependency object/value converter class. The `MarkupExtension` could mirror its properties and forward the values in to it. But I don't see any ROI at all in going that far.

Comment: I really like #2 now that I can see it in code... I just wish that there was some way to reference a property without having to do a binding or jumping through a thousand different hoops like this, but I can live with this option.

Comment: Another option as mm8 suggests is to derive your valueconverter from DependencyObject rather than from MarkupExtension. That means you have to create an instance of it in resources, but that's not the end of the world. And then you can give it bindable dependency properties.